# Which Big Data technology stack is most suitable for processing tweets, extracting/expanding URLs and pushing (only) new links into 3rd party system?

Tags: bigdata, tools, data-stream-mining

*(Note: Pulled this question from the [list of questions in Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55053/data-science/57398#57398), but believe the question is self explanatory. That said, believe I get the general intent of the question, and as a result likely able to field any questions on the question that might pop-up.)*

**Which Big Data technology stack is most suitable for processing tweets, extracting/expanding URLs and pushing (only) new links into 3rd party system?**

Comment: About how much tweets a "run" are we talking?

Comment: It's hard to know without a range of tweets, 1000, 100,000 full datahose etc.

Comment: @Johnny000: [500 million Tweets a day](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/new-tweets-per-second-record-and-how); my understanding is that Twitter limits streams to vendors based on trust/need, but to insure the solution covers the current daily averages, the solution should account what is the max, or you're able to reference as the max via a reliable source other than yourself.

Comment: Here's more information, appear the "firehose" data feed is pricy, so guessing it would be more relevant to limit input to the volume produce via the [Twitter Streaming APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/streaming) via the Public Stream; [guide to processing the data is here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/processing#Scaling).

Comment: Public Stream is a random sample of the "firehose" and appears to 1% of its total volume; meaning I estimate the feed to be 5 million tweets per day, and spikes might reach 1432 tweets per second; appears the spike must be account for, otherwise the feed gets discounted.

Comment: I'd suggest Apache Kafka as message store and any stream processing solution of your choice like Apache Camel or Twitter Storm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest [Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org) as message store and any stream processing solution of your choice like [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org) or [Twitter Storm](https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm)